# How to fix button in end of the screen

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, uibutton, screen

Hi I have this UI and I want to set button in end of the screen. How can I do this?
[image: this is my UI]

This is my code. This code is show how I design this UI. I want to know how I can set button in end of screen.I set the up
TextField in padding To be spaced with the button.I try to increase the value of padding but it don't work good. Do I have other solution?

```
Container(
    height: height,
    width: width,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 10, top: 30),
            child: new InputField(
              textController: receiverController,
              hint: 'نام گیرنده پیام را وارد کنید',
              label: 'گیرنده',
              obscure: false,
              icon: Icons.person_add_alt_1_outlined,
              radius: 15,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 10),
            child: new InputField(
              textController: subjectController,
              hint: 'عنوان پیام را وارد کنید',
              label: ' عنوان ',
              obscure: false,
              icon: Icons.title,
              radius: 15,
              // suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 10),
            child: new InputField(
              textController: textController,
              // hint: 'پیام ',
              label: ' متن',
              obscure: false,
              icon: Icons.message,
              radius: 15,
              // suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock),
            ),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80),
            child: new ButtonTheme(
                minWidth: width * .25,
                height: 50,
                child: new RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    this.newmessageBloc.add(new NewmessageEventSend(
                        receiver: receiverController.text,
                        subject: subjectController.text,
                        text: textController.text));
                  },
                  child: new Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Text(
                        'ارسال',
                        style: new TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 16),
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.send_rounded,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  color: new Color(0xff333399),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                  ),
                )),
          )
```

Comment: SUGGESTION: Consider using MaterialApp as your root widget (if you're not already).  Then  `MaterialApp > home: Scaffold()`, and `Scaffold > persistentFooterButtons:`, and add your button(s) there: https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-material-design-using-scaffold-appbar-body-bottom-navigation-floating-action-f84d71e68c76

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `Expanded` widget on a Column and after that write you'r btn like this:

```
Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: new Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Padding(
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 10, top: 30),
                    child: Text(""),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                  new Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 10),
                    child: Text(""),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 10,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80),
          child: new ButtonTheme(
              minWidth: 25,
              height: 50,
              child: new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // this.newmessageBloc.add(new NewmessageEventSend(
                  //     receiver: receiverController.text,
                  //     subject: subjectController.text,
                  //     text: textController.text));
                },
                child: new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Text(
                      'ارسال',
                      style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      Icons.send_rounded,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                color: new Color(0xff333399),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                ),
              )),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

sorry, I was forced to remove some part of code, because i didn't know about them.